# Putting database field into a label

Tags: database, vb.net, label

I am having difficulties putting a database field record into the text of a label. The database is called 'task.accdb' and the table I want is called 'QuestionAndAnswer'. I am making a quiz program where I input the question from the database into a label. 
The problem is nothing happens to the label, it stays the same instead of changing to hold the input of the database record.

Here is a picture of the form:
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajWwx.png)

Below is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class qa2

Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim askquestions(1, 2)
Dim noq As String
Dim score As Integer = 0
'  Dim answers(3)

Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\15.4\15.4\bin\Debug\task.accdb"

Private Sub Questions_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TaskDataSet1.Results_Query' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet11.Results_Query)


    Student_Menu.Hide()

    noq = InputBox("How many questions would you like to do? You can choose from 1 to 10.")
    Label2.Text = noq

    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
       " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\15.4\15.4\bin\Debug\task.accdb"
    Dim dtIDs As New DataTable

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString:=ConnectString)
    Dim daIDs As New OleDbDataAdapter _
        ("Select [ID] From QuestionAndAnswer", con)

    If Student_Menu.btnTheory.Enabled = True Then


        daIDs.Fill(DataSet11)

        con.Open()

        OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11)
        Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataSet11, _
                                     "QuestionAndAnswer.Question")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Its likely blank  because nothing was read - you cant fill a dataset before you open a connection.  That should throw an exception, but since you have the code in Form Load you probably wont see it.  Move the code to a button click to verify the error

Comment: i moved the code to a button and there was no change. then i created a function, still no change and then i put the fill code after the opening of the connection and still no change to the label. im so stuck!

Comment: i have resolved the problem